# How to validate TLS certificate manually when using CFSockets on iOS?

Tags: ios, sockets, ssl

I'm creating a connection to a server using `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost`. This server is using a self-signed certificate and I have to validate it.
I've been trying to find any way to retrieve the server certificate but I am lost, can't find any method/class which would allow me to retrieve it.

I will be grateful for pointing out how can I get it in a code like this:

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) address, (UInt32) port, &readStream, &writeStream);

NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *) readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *) writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

NSDictionary *settings = @{(NSString *) kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain: @NO};

CFReadStreamSetProperty((__bridge CFReadStreamRef) inputStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (__bridge CFTypeRef) settings);

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During yet another session of googling, I have finally stumbled upon one of the few rare Apple Docs which describe a process clearly:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2232/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012884-CH1-SECCFSOCKETSTREAM

and here's a sample code provided by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html